# Only Tensors of floating point and complex dtype can require gradients

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient-descent

I am receiving the following error when I run a convolution operation inside a `torch.no_grad()` context:

> ```
> RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating-point and complex dtype can require gradients.
> ```

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch


with torch.no_grad():
    ker_t = torch.tensor([[1, -1] ,[-1, 1]])
    in_t = torch.tensor([ [14, 7, 6, 2,] , [4 ,8 ,11 ,1], [3, 5, 9 ,10], [12, 15, 16, 13] ])
    print(in_t.shape)
    in_t = torch.unsqueeze(in_t,0)
    in_t = torch.unsqueeze(in_t,0)
    print(in_t.shape)

    conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=2,stride=2,dtype=torch.long)
    conv.weight[:] = ker_t
    conv(in_t)
```

Now I am sure if I turn my input into floats this message will go away, but I want to work in integers.

But I was under the impression that if I am in a `with torch.no_grad()` context it should turn off the need for gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for gradients comes from `nn.Conv2d` when it registers the weights of the convolution layer.
However, if you are only after the forward pass, you do not need to use a convolution *layer*: you can use the underlying convolution *function*:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

ker_t = torch.tensor([[1, -1] ,[-1, 1]])[None, None, ...]
in_t = torch.tensor([ [14, 7, 6, 2,] , [4 ,8 ,11 ,1], [3, 5, 9 ,10], [12, 15, 16, 13] ])[None, None, ...]
out = nnf.conv2d(in_t, ker_t, stride=2)
```

Will give you this output:

```py
tensor([[[[11, -6],
          [ 1, -4]]]])
```